# Delete all files and directories - except specified

Tags: linux, delete-file

Been looking for this for a while.
We have a common directory where everyone has rwx rights. To keep this from growing out of proportions, I need to clear this once a month. No problem, except I'm supposed to keep 2 directories - one of which has spaces in its name.

I have this find command that lists what should be deleted;

```
find /COMMON/* | grep -v 'keepthis' | grep -v 'keep this too'
```

However, I'm at at total loss as to how I could `rm` or `delete` the output

I've googled an found millions of suggestions but they don't fit - I believe it's because of the spaces in the directory name. 
So: how should the command end in order to work?

Comment: Please at least include the operating system or environment you're working in. A single tag on the question of `delete` is totally meaningless without some other information; it could apply to Windows/*nix/a DBMS/C/C++ or any number of other topics. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send to xargs and then rm:

```
find /COMMON/* -maxdepth 0 | grep -v 'keepthis' | grep -v 'keep this too' | xargs -rd '\n' rm -r --
```

**edited** after your suggestion :)

Comment: yeah, but I guess he needs automated process, without asking to remove. But it still doesn't solve the problem he has I think :|

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work
- sorry I can't be more specific but neither of the suggested ways removed anything. I'm on SLES11, btw

Comment: Sorry hadn't refreshed. Have only checked before xargs were there. Will check again.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. All files that were supposed to be deleted are gone. Now all we need is for the unwanted directories to go as well. Thanks so far!

Comment: Worked fine. some messages "no such file or directory" but it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Got it - added "-maxdepth 0" before grep-ing

Comment: So the syntax that did what I wanted, without errors:  <br/>
`find /COMMON/* -maxdepth 0 | grep -v 'keepthis' | grep -v 'keep this too' | xargs -rd '\n' rm -r --`  <br/>
If I had enough reputation points I would vote this